# SQL-Server 2005 default trace log file not inherits directory permissions

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, log-files, file-permissions

I need to backup the SQL-Server 2005 default trace log files (%sqlserverpath%\MSSQL\LOG\log_*.trc) and when it is created it isnt inheriting the directory file permissions (Windows 2003 Server) so I get access denied to do the file copy with my "backup service" user. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally on my maintenance plan (a batch file on task scheduler) I add a change permision code like this:

```
cacls "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\*.trc" /E /G backupserviceaccount:R /T
```

Jope this help someone else!

Answer (score 2):

> SQL Server now ACLs the trace files
>   with the same user permissions as that
>   of the database files.   This is
>   usually the service account SQL Server
>   executes under and the
>   Computer\Administrators group.   The
>   permissions of the directory are no
>   longer inherited.
>
> *The owner of the trace files must explicitly grant security permissions
>   to others in accordance with security
>   policies and company guidelines.*

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/06/25/how-it-works-trace-trc-file-security.aspx

Comment: Thanks pk, I understand, but I dind't like it, becasuse I don't want to check if a new file is created in each database server every day.